# How to download a file as string with javascript or php for speedtest?

Tags: c#, php, javascript, download

With c# I download files with webclient as string in order to check download speed, how can I do this with javascript or PHP?
Here is my c# sample.

```
  Uri URL = new Uri("https://www.example.com/File512kb");
  WebClient wc = new WebClient();
  double starttime = Environment.TickCount;
  string file = wc.DownloadString(URL);     //download this file as string so I won't need to save it to local disk.
  stopWatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds;
  double endtime = Environment.TickCount;
  double milisecs = endtime - starttime;
```

Thanks...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
var start = new Date();
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.example.com/File512kb"
}).done(function() {
    console.log(new Date() - start);
});
```

This returns the time passed in milliseconds. The function does use jQuery, however, since that's a nice'n easy way to make AJAX calls.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be 100% accurate, but you can use `file_get_contents()` and `microtime()` in PHP.

https://www.php.net/file_get_contents
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$fStart = microtime( true );

file_get_contents( 'http://www.example.com/File512kb' );

$fEnd = microtime( true );

echo $fEnd - $fStart;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would go about it in PHP:

```
<?php

    set_time_limit(0);
    $start_time = microtime(true);
    $file = file_get_contents('http://somefileorother.com/file');
    $end_time = microtime(true) - $start_time;

    echo $end_time;
```